Bash script to open multiple Excel files?
As part of my workflow, I often have multiple Excel files open on my Mac, and often they are the same files for any given task.  Thus, I thought I would write a Bash script to open them all at once (file names changed for privacy):
    case $foobaz in
        1)
            open "./foobar/foo.xlsm" &
            open "./foobar/bar.csv" &
            open "./foobar/baz.xlsx" &
            echo "Foobar opened."
            ;;

The case is just a number I type in to tell the script what workflow I want.  There are other values than just 1 but since they have identical code, just different files.
What happens when I run this is the script opens one or more of the files (it is not consistent which files and how many) and then hangs.  I probably just did something stupid writing the code, since I am relatively new to Bash scripting, but I would like to know what I did wrong in order to learn more.

I assume you are using OSX ?  You might want to make that clear.   Also, can we assume that $foobaz is set to 1 before this code snippet?

@davidgo Yes, I am using macOS for this, and yes, we can assume that $foobaz is set to 1.

Knowing Excel, I would not be surprised if launching (opening) files in quick succession being "too much".

As above. Also, try to use to use Excel directly, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6 and e.g. \t. I don't know if it's the same on Mac.

"and then hangs" – Do you mean the script never gets to and past echo "Foobar opened."?

@KamilMaciorowski that is correct.  Sorry I took so long to respond.
